# Set yAxis background color in Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to color Y axes on a Highstock chart, I tried changing the plotBackgroundColor but it changes the whole plot area.

2 images are more than 2 thousand words:

[image]

On the left I have my current result, it changes the whole plot area background color, so is not easy to see where a chart ends and the next one starts, On the right is the expected result, each axis is separated by the background color and a gray border.

This is my code:

```js
var p0 = [
  [1540166400000,122.85],
  [1540170000000,122.33],
  [1540173600000,120.96],
  [1540177200000,120.77],
  [1540180800000,120.84],
  [1540184400000,120.61],
  [1540188000000,120.83],
  [1540191600000,121.04],
  [1540195200000,120.67],
  [1540198800000,121.05],
  [1540202400000,122.29],
  [1540206000000,122.45],
  [1540209600000,123.13],
  [1540213200000,123.74],
  [1540216800000,124.07],
  [1540224000000,123.28],
  [1540227600000,122.59],
  [1540231200000,122.98],
  [1540234800000,123.51],
  [1540238400000,123.38],
  [1540242000000,123.45],
  [1540245600000,123.15],
  [1540249200000,123.72],
  [1540252800000,123.65],
  [1540256400000,123.65],
  [1540260000000,123.28],
  [1540263600000,122.56],
  [1540267200000,122.41],
  [1540270800000,122.23],
  [1540274400000,122.22],
  [1540278000000,122.4],
  [1540281600000,121.57],
  [1540285200000,121.69],
  [1540288800000,121.98]];
var p1 = [
  [1540166400000,127.27],
  [1540170000000,126.74],
  [1540173600000,125.46],
  [1540177200000,125.49],
  [1540180800000,125.71],
  [1540184400000,125.49],
  [1540188000000,125.57],
  [1540191600000,126.02],
  [1540195200000,125.62],
  [1540198800000,125.88],
  [1540202400000,126.49],
  [1540206000000,127.11],
  [1540209600000,127.97],
  [1540213200000,128.84],
  [1540216800000,128.66],
  [1540224000000,127.63],
  [1540227600000,126.98],
  [1540231200000,127.63],
  [1540234800000,127.77],
  [1540238400000,127.21],
  [1540242000000,127.24],
  [1540245600000,126.87],
  [1540249200000,126.99],
  [1540252800000,127.04],
  [1540256400000,127.47],
  [1540260000000,126.91],
  [1540263600000,126.3],
  [1540267200000,126.36],
  [1540270800000,126.07],
  [1540274400000,126.09],
  [1540278000000,126.18],
  [1540281600000,125.54],
  [1540285200000,125.7],
  [1540288800000,126.06]];

chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
chart: {
 renderTo: "container",
 backgroundColor:'#EBEBEB',
 plotBackgroundColor:'#FFFFFF',
  plotBorderColor: '#999999',
  plotBorderWidth: 2
},
title: {
 text: "Coloring axis",
},
legend: {
 enabled: false
},
xAxis: {
 ordinal: false
},
yAxis: [
 {
  minorTicks: 1,
  height: "46%",
  top: "4%"
 },
 {
  minorTicks: 1,
  height: "46%",
  top: "54%"
 }
],
series: [
 {
  name: "Val1 1",
  data: p0,
  yAxis: 0,
 },
 {
  name: "Presión 2",
  data: p1,
  yAxis: 1,
 },
]
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround to achieve what you are after can be done by using a third yAxis, like this:

```
{
  height: "4%",
  top: "50%",
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  minorGridLineWidth: 0,
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  plotBands: [{
    color: '#EBEBEB',
    borderColor:'#999999',
    borderWidth: 2,
    from: 0.05,
    to: 0.95,
  }
}
```

```js
var p0 = [
  [1540166400000,122.85],
  [1540170000000,122.33],
  [1540173600000,120.96],
  [1540177200000,120.77],
  [1540180800000,120.84],
  [1540184400000,120.61],
  [1540188000000,120.83],
  [1540191600000,121.04],
  [1540195200000,120.67],
  [1540198800000,121.05],
  [1540202400000,122.29],
  [1540206000000,122.45],
  [1540209600000,123.13],
  [1540213200000,123.74],
  [1540216800000,124.07],
  [1540224000000,123.28],
  [1540227600000,122.59],
  [1540231200000,122.98],
  [1540234800000,123.51],
  [1540238400000,123.38],
  [1540242000000,123.45],
  [1540245600000,123.15],
  [1540249200000,123.72],
  [1540252800000,123.65],
  [1540256400000,123.65],
  [1540260000000,123.28],
  [1540263600000,122.56],
  [1540267200000,122.41],
  [1540270800000,122.23],
  [1540274400000,122.22],
  [1540278000000,122.4],
  [1540281600000,121.57],
  [1540285200000,121.69],
  [1540288800000,121.98]];
var p1 = [
  [1540166400000,127.27],
  [1540170000000,126.74],
  [1540173600000,125.46],
  [1540177200000,125.49],
  [1540180800000,125.71],
  [1540184400000,125.49],
  [1540188000000,125.57],
  [1540191600000,126.02],
  [1540195200000,125.62],
  [1540198800000,125.88],
  [1540202400000,126.49],
  [1540206000000,127.11],
  [1540209600000,127.97],
  [1540213200000,128.84],
  [1540216800000,128.66],
  [1540224000000,127.63],
  [1540227600000,126.98],
  [1540231200000,127.63],
  [1540234800000,127.77],
  [1540238400000,127.21],
  [1540242000000,127.24],
  [1540245600000,126.87],
  [1540249200000,126.99],
  [1540252800000,127.04],
  [1540256400000,127.47],
  [1540260000000,126.91],
  [1540263600000,126.3],
  [1540267200000,126.36],
  [1540270800000,126.07],
  [1540274400000,126.09],
  [1540278000000,126.18],
  [1540281600000,125.54],
  [1540285200000,125.7],
  [1540288800000,126.06]];

chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
chart: {
 renderTo: "container",
 backgroundColor:'#EBEBEB',
 plotBackgroundColor:'#FFFFFF',
  plotBorderColor: '#999999',
  plotBorderWidth: 2
},
title: {
 text: "Coloring axis",
},
legend: {
 enabled: false
},
xAxis: {
 ordinal: false
},
yAxis: [
 {
  minorTicks: 1,
  height: "46%",
  top: "4%",
  plotLines: [
  ]
 },
 {
  minorTicks: 1,
  height: "46%",
  top: "54%",
  plotLines: [
  ]
 },
  {
   height: "4%",
    top: "50%",
    labels: {
     enabled: false
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    plotBands: [{
     color: '#EBEBEB',
      borderColor:'#999999',
      borderWidth: 2,
      
      from: 0.05,
      to: 0.95,
    }]
  }
],
series: [
 {
  name: "Val1 1",
  data: p0,
  yAxis: 0,
 },
 {
  name: "Presión 2",
  data: p1,
  yAxis: 1,
 },
]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

**JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/q826ze9v/8/

The "correct" way to achieve what you are after would be to follow highcharts' syncronized chart example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts. This is more complicated, but allows you much more customization, and would probably prove easier to work with long term.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it using [highcharts SVGRenderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect), drawing white rectangles for each axis at z-index:-1 to draw it on the background.

I hope this helps someone!

```js
var p0 = [
  [1540166400000,122.85],
  [1540170000000,122.33],
  [1540173600000,120.96],
  [1540177200000,120.77],
  [1540180800000,120.84],
  [1540184400000,120.61],
  [1540188000000,120.83],
  [1540191600000,121.04],
  [1540195200000,120.67],
  [1540198800000,121.05],
  [1540202400000,122.29],
  [1540206000000,122.45],
  [1540209600000,123.13],
  [1540213200000,123.74],
  [1540216800000,124.07],
  [1540224000000,123.28],
  [1540227600000,122.59],
  [1540231200000,122.98],
  [1540234800000,123.51],
  [1540238400000,123.38],
  [1540242000000,123.45],
  [1540245600000,123.15],
  [1540249200000,123.72],
  [1540252800000,123.65],
  [1540256400000,123.65],
  [1540260000000,123.28],
  [1540263600000,122.56],
  [1540267200000,122.41],
  [1540270800000,122.23],
  [1540274400000,122.22],
  [1540278000000,122.4],
  [1540281600000,121.57],
  [1540285200000,121.69],
  [1540288800000,121.98]];
var p1 = [
  [1540166400000,127.27],
  [1540170000000,126.74],
  [1540173600000,125.46],
  [1540177200000,125.49],
  [1540180800000,125.71],
  [1540184400000,125.49],
  [1540188000000,125.57],
  [1540191600000,126.02],
  [1540195200000,125.62],
  [1540198800000,125.88],
  [1540202400000,126.49],
  [1540206000000,127.11],
  [1540209600000,127.97],
  [1540213200000,128.84],
  [1540216800000,128.66],
  [1540224000000,127.63],
  [1540227600000,126.98],
  [1540231200000,127.63],
  [1540234800000,127.77],
  [1540238400000,127.21],
  [1540242000000,127.24],
  [1540245600000,126.87],
  [1540249200000,126.99],
  [1540252800000,127.04],
  [1540256400000,127.47],
  [1540260000000,126.91],
  [1540263600000,126.3],
  [1540267200000,126.36],
  [1540270800000,126.07],
  [1540274400000,126.09],
  [1540278000000,126.18],
  [1540281600000,125.54],
  [1540285200000,125.7],
  [1540288800000,126.06]];

chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
chart: {
 renderTo: "container",
 backgroundColor:'#EBEBEB'
},
title: {
 text: "Coloring axis",
},
legend: {
 enabled: false
},
xAxis: {
 ordinal: false
},
yAxis: [
 {
  minorTicks: 1,
  height: "46%",
  top: "4%"
 },
 {
  minorTicks: 1,
  height: "46%",
  top: "54%"
 }
],
series: [
 {
  name: "Val1 1",
  data: p0,
  yAxis: 0,
 },
 {
  name: "Presión 2",
  data: p1,
  yAxis: 1,
 },
]
}, function (chart) { // on complete
  var yaxisColl = chart.yAxis;
  for(f=0;f<yaxisColl.length;f++){
    axis = yaxisColl[f];
    chart.renderer.rect(10, axis.top, axis.width, axis.height, 0, 2)
    .attr({
     'stroke-width': 2,
     stroke: '#999999',
     fill: '#FFFFFF',
     zIndex: -1
    })
    .add();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it using `plotBands` on each `yAxis`:

```
yAxis: [
    {
        minorTicks: 1,
        height: "46%",
        top: "4%",
    plotBands: [{
        from:-1000,
      to:1000,
      color:'rgb(255,255,255)'
    }]
    },
    {
        minorTicks: 1,
        height: "46%",
        top: "54%",
    plotBands: [{
        from:-1000,
      to:1000,
      color:'rgb(255,255,255)'
    }]
    }
]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/k2syL51r/